# How is ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization metric caluclated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

How Is ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization actually calculated? It is obvious that it gets the average, but what is the actual time duration? Average of last 15 minutes? Less?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Average" in `ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization` does not mean a "time duration". The "Average" in this metric refers to  an average of `CPUUtilization` overall **all tasks in the service**.

The details how this is calculated are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html#service_utilization):

> Service utilization is measured as the percentage of CPU and memory that is used by the Amazon ECS **tasks that belong to a service** on a cluster when compared to the CPU and memory that is specified in the service's task definition.

The metrics are collected in **1 minute** intervals.

The "time duration" has meaning when you define a **Target Tracking** scaling policy to auto-scale your service.

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation!

Comment: The question asks about the averaging duration. e.g. the unix `top` command shows the system load (equivalent to CPU utilization) averaged over 1, 5 & 15 minutes. While the metrics are collected at 1 minute intervals, it will be interesting to know the averaging duration.