# ECS scale in with capacity provider to minimum capacity of ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have ECS cluster configured with target tracking policy on service and capacity provider which managing ASG autoscaling

In my cluster count of minimum and maximum tasks  in service and minimum and maximum capacity in ASG the same .

When performed scale in action, tasks decreased to minimum count. But ASG still have 1 or more unused ( task not placed on this EC2 instance ) ec2 instance

How can i configure my cluster with capacity provider to perform scale in to minimum count ASG capacity ?

```
# CLUSTER
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "default" {
  name               = local.name
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.asg.name]
  tags               = local.tags

  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    base = 0
    capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.asg.name
    weight = 1
  }
}

# SERVICE
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service" {
  name            = "${local.name}-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.default.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task.arn
  health_check_grace_period_seconds = 60

  deployment_maximum_percent         = 50
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100


  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = element(module.aws-alb-common-module.target_group_arns, 1)
    container_name   = local.name
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [desired_count, task_definition]
  }


}

# CAPACITY PROVIDER
resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "asg" {
  name = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_nodes.name

  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn         = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_nodes.arn
    managed_termination_protection = "DISABLED"

    managed_scaling {
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 10
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
    }
  }
}

# SERVICE AUTOSCALING POLICY

resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
  max_capacity       = 20
  min_capacity       = 2
  resource_id        = "service/${local.name}/${aws_ecs_service.ecs_service.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_policy" {
  name = "${local.name}-scale-policy"
  policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 2

  }


# ASG
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_nodes" {
  name_prefix           = "${local.name}-node"
  max_size              = 20
  min_size              = 2
  vpc_zone_identifier   = local.subnets_ids
  protect_from_scale_in = false

  mixed_instances_policy {
    instances_distribution {
      on_demand_percentage_above_base_capacity = local.spot
    }
    launch_template {
      launch_template_specification {
        launch_template_id = aws_launch_template.node.id
        version            = "$Latest"
      }

      dynamic "override" {
        for_each = local.instance_types
        content {
          instance_type     = override.key
          weighted_capacity = override.value
        }
      }
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
    propagate_at_launch = true
    value               = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it perhaps related to the base = 1 setting?

Comment: i try to set base = 1 or base = 2 but have  4 instances or 3 not 1 .. or minimum capacity of asg  (2)

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the original question, but your clarification that ASG min capacity is 2 makes it clearer.
managed_termination_protection can cause a delay in terminating instances even if there are no running tasks on them. Have you left the config long enough to be sure it's not behaving as designed? See the "Scaling in" section of https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deep-dive-on-amazon-ecs-cluster-auto-scaling/ for an example.

Comment: I disabled termination protection and disable protected instances from scale in in asg . ASG scaling out to 10 but scaling in only to 6 not to minimum ( 2) but tasks scale in to minumum (2)

Comment: Could you append to your post the current version of the code, plus the code and variable definitions for aws_autoscaling_group.asg including target tracking scaling policy and ASG instance scale-in protection config? Also, are there any ELBs involved? And have you checked for Instance-level scale-in protection settings?

Comment: ок let me some time

Comment: sorry for long response i try to solve problem myself . Now my result i have 3 ec2 instances but not minimum (2) . I am using ALB ... and ec2 instances termination protection disabled

Comment: i edited my post and add terraform code that using now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is likely that the `predefined_metric_specification` block `target_value = 2` is the cpu usage trigger level (percent), not the minimum capacity. The instance is probably being kept alive by background processes using small amounts of CPU.

By the way, the managed_termination_protection setting is probably worth reenabling.

**Update in response to comments on 25/09:**

Ok, it's entirely possible I'm wrong here (especially as I haven't used this feature myself yet), and if so I'm very happy to learn from it.

But this is how I read the mentioned documentation in relation to your config: The key phrase is *The target capacity value is used as the target value for the **CloudWatch metric** used in the Amazon ECS-managed target tracking scaling policy*. The cloudwatch metric you have selected is ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization, which is discussed at [How is ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization metric caluclated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441525/how-is-ecsserviceaveragecpuutilization-metric-caluclated). So the target=2 you have configured means 2% average CPU utilisation.

I admit I mistakenly assumed the CPU metric was an EC2-instance-level average. But in either case, having your trigger value set to 2% CPU is likely to cause/maintain scaleout when none is needed.

It's also possible you've found the simple explanation for the behaviour you're seeing, i.e. the *but this behavior is not guaranteed at all times* statement. However I suspect that statement applies more to the extreme example of target 100% where one can expect to see anomalies, just as that can be expected at the similarly extreme 2%.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood something but if i remove predefined_metric_specification  how cluster will be scaling out when i have huge amount of requests on my alb ?  I use predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"  as metric for action scale out

Comment: You don't need to remove that setting, just increase the `target_value = ` value to the average CPU utilisation level you want as the trigger -- 75 for example.

Comment: i tried to set target_value = 7 before but its not helps me :(( and tasks ( triggered by this target_value )  always scaling in to minimum (2) .. problem only with empty ec2 instances that i still have ( not scaling in to 2 )

Comment: For Target capacity %, if managed scaling is enabled, specify an integer between 1 and 100. The target capacity value is used as the target value for the CloudWatch metric used in the Amazon ECS-managed target tracking scaling policy. This target capacity value is matched on a best effort basis. For example, a value of 100 will result in the Amazon EC2 instances in your Auto Scaling group being completely utilized and any instances not running any tasks will be scaled in, **but this behavior is not guaranteed at all times.**

Comment: This part of AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers.html

Comment: See response in update above as it's too long to add here.

Comment: **Thanks for your answers and your help!! 
I set ASG minimum to 0 ( but in service tasks capacity minimum 2 ) . Also i deleted ec2 instance weight value in launch template ( mixed types of instances ) . In service policy setted target value to 20 ( but also worked when target_value = 2 )  And its solved my problem**

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'll have to learn how all this fits together.

Comment: Would you mind updating your initial post with a summary of the solution and a code snippet please?